# How to properly configure routes at Pyramid Framework?

Tags: pyramid

I want to register a request handler, but don't want to use scan method.

Why do I need to call both methods(add_route and add_view) instead of one?

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config


@view_config(name='home')
def home(request):
    return Response('Welcome!')


def add_view(config, handler, name, path):
    config.add_route(name, path)
    config.add_view(handler, name=name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    add_view(config, home, 'home', '/')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: For "simple routing" see http://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.core.route.html?highlight=simple_route#websauna.system.core.route.simple_route - this is not packaged for Pyramid core (yet), but you might look inspiration if you have multiple routes.

Answer (score 5):

(1) If you use the @view_config decorator in Pyramid, you must use config.scan(). (This is declarative configuration.) See [Adding View Configuration Using the @view_config Decorator](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#adding-view-configuration-using-the-view-config-decorator).

Alternatively you could use imperative configuration using `config.add_view()`. See [Adding View Configuration Using add_view()](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#mapping-views-using-imperative-config-section).

(2) Perhaps you should ask, "Why do I want to configure both my route and view with a single declaration?" Doing so prevents you from assigning multiple views to a single route. The convenience of saving one line of code has its drawbacks.

In Pyramid, declaring a route and a view separately allows you to assign many views to a single route. For example, assign one view for a GET request, and another for a POST request, for the same route. As one side benefit, it makes creating RESTful APIs less onerous. For more information, see the Pyramid documentation, [Pyramid Introduction - View predicates and many views per route](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introduction.html#view-predicates-and-many-views-per-route).

Comment: "Doing so prevents you from assigning multiple views to a single route." while this is true, this is not needed for the most use cases. For a "Don't repeat yourself" solution minimizing the lines of code see http://websauna.org/docs/api/websauna.system.core.route.html?highlight=simple_route#websauna.system.core.route.simple_route

Comment: however the `simple_route` as a *decorator* is not without its drawbacks as discussed in [Pyramid design defense](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/designdefense.html#routes-need-relative-ordering)